# Download email attachment

Tags: regex, perl, email-attachments

I am reading email from an IMAP server using the
[`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient)
module over SSL.
I am able to extract the body of the email but not the attachment.

Please suggest how can I download the email attachment? I want to avoid downloading  attachment inside the attachments. i.e. multilevel attachments.

Here is how I am fetching the email body

```
my $struct = $client->get_bodystructure( $msg_id );

if ( $struct->bodytype ne "MULTIPART" ) {
    print "\n BodyEnc:" . $struct->bodyenc();
}

my $rDecode = decode( $struct, $client, $msg_id );

if ( $rDecode ne "" && ( length( $rDecode ) > 2 ) ) {
    print( $rDecode . "\n" );
}

foreach my $dumpme ( $struct->bodystructure() ) {

    if ( $dumpme->bodytype() eq "MULTIPART" ) {
        next;
    }

    $rDecode = "";

    $rDecode = decode( $dumpme, $client, $msg_id );

    if ( ( $rDecode ne "" ) && ( length( $rDecode ) > 2 ) ) {
        print( $rDecode . "\n" );
    }
}

sub decode {

    my ( $process, $imap, $msg_id ) = @_;

    if ( $process->bodytype eq "TEXT" ) {

        if ( $process->bodyenc eq "base64" ) {

            return decode_base64( $imap->bodypart_string( $msg_id, $process->id ) );
        }
        elsif ( index( " -7bit- -8bit- -quoted-printable- ", lc( $process->bodyenc ) ) != -1 ) {

            return $imap->bodypart_string( $msg_id, $process->id );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to download the email attachment. I just needed to create a new file with the same extension as the attached file in the email and write the content to it by decoding the attachment content.